# The preposition for "lyrics" and "song"

Tags: prepositions

> lyrics for a song.

or

> lyrics to a song.

or

> lyrics in a song.

Which does sound good?

Comment: Discounting the fact that [*lyric*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lyric) actually means "the words of a song," I would just say *song lyrics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The lyrics of a song" is a common way to say it. Also common are "the lyrics to (song name)", "a song's lyrics", "The lyrics in a song", or "the lyrics for (song name)", though the last two are less common.